# Electron app with database

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, electron

I'm creating a web app for ticket reservation. The only problem is the database. I don't want to tell my client to install XAMPP or set a database, etc.

Is there any way to package the app with the database?

Comment: sqlite might be an option

Comment: check this out using sqlite with electron https://github.com/sjmelia/electron-boilerplate-sqlite

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[SQLite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-sqlite3) is a good option for a local database that you can ship with your application. It won't require the user to setup or install any extra dependencies. It's certainly not as full featured as a full on server, but it should be good enough for a local desktop app.

Comment: where do you use it, in main or renderer?

Comment: In the main. For security reasons.